# SignalR Silverlight and LoadBalancer

Tags: silverlight, signalr

We have an application with Silverlight 5 and WCF RIA backend.
Our Client's environment has load balancing but has only 30 - 40 users.

We wanted to use SignalR for messaging, but instead of using a backplane, i am planning to 
install a seperate MVC service as Hub which will sit outside the Loadbalancer, where all clients can connect to.

Is this approach okay for a small user base (30 - 40 users)?  And since its going to be cross domain, do i need to copy clientaccesspolicy.xml to the root folders for silverlight to work ? Or do i need to configure SignalR to allow cross domain?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both.
Enabling cross domain on SignalR server allows requests to be processed on server side.
Adding clientaccesspolicy.xml allows Silverlight to establish the connection.

Comment: Thank you ! would you show me a sample code how to enable cross domain on the SignalR side ? I am using a MVC service for SignalR.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation on asp.net/signalr

Comment: on the MVC side i tried var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfiguration.EnableCrossDomain = true;
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(hubConfiguration); On the Silverlight side i added a clientaccesspolicy.xml in the root folder. But Cross domain is still not working. please let me know what i am missing, Thanks !

Comment: This is the code on silverlight side var conn = new HubConnection("http://testserver:8088/MVC/");
var hub = conn.CreateProxy("SignalRMVC.Hubs.ChatHub");
hub.On<string>("NewMessage", message => Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Published: " + message)));
conn.Start();